geom_sf does not match layer for geom_point
I am trying to map a variable uisng GGplot, but the layers don't match is there a way I can fix this so they match?
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = sf_data) +
  geom_point(data=point_data,aes(x, y))


I have a map, but the points don't match.

Welcome to SO! To help others to help you, you should provide a reproducible example providing your datasets sf_data and points_data so others can reproduce your problem. Read this for more infomration on how to prepare a REPREX. Also, you should explain better what's your problem. Why your points don't match? How are they suppose to be? Can you provide the desired result?

Hi, I will try to get an example to share. the image I entered tries to show the issue, pretty much the points i have overlayed stick out the sides of the map I have, is there a way I can get the points to all fit inside the map?

It looks like you have a grid of points covering the rectangle of points spanning in each cardinal direction. Is the idea you want to filter your points so you only display the ones that are within mapped regions?

yes, I only want the points that would fit within the map?

Given the use of geom_point() in your example code, this repex assumes your point_data object is a dataframe. Here is the workflow to achieve what you want:

Convert point_data to an sf object with the same CRS as sf_data (in this example, NAD27)
Use st_intersection() to return only those points that fall within the extent of the sf_data polygons

Note that you will get a warning running this code which you can safely ignore. It just means that the CRS of the data are a geographic coordinate system instead of a projected coordinate system. Depending on the CRS of your actual data, you may or may not get a waring.
Load required packages and create example data
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Example polygon sf data
sf_data <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

# Example points df
point_data <- st_make_grid(sf_data, cellsize = 0.5) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_cast("POINT") %>%
  rename(geometry = "x") %>%
  mutate(x = st_coordinates(.)[,1],
         y = st_coordinates(.)[,2]) %>%
  st_drop_geometry()

head(point_data)
#           x        y
# 1 -84.32385 33.88199
# 2 -83.82385 33.88199
# 3 -83.82385 34.38199
# 4 -84.32385 34.38199
# 5 -84.32385 33.88199
# 6 -83.82385 33.88199

Convert point_data to a point sf object, assign CRS so it matches the CRS of sf_data, subset data
# Convert point_data dataframe to point sf object and assign CRS from sf_data
sf_points <- st_as_sf(point_data, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = st_crs(sf_data))

# Subset points using sf_data as the st_intersection() object
sf_points1 <- st_intersection(sf_points, sf_data)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = sf_data, colour = "grey75") +
  geom_sf(data = sf_points, aes(colour = "All Points")) +
  geom_sf(data = sf_points1, aes(colour = "Subset points")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())


